# Pinescript how to check if price is inside a rectangle?

Tags: pine-script, trading

I am new to Pinescript so please excuse me if this is a dumb question. How do I check if the price of the ticker is inside a drawn rectangle on the chart?

Comment: Do you manually draw the box or is it drawn by the indicator?

Comment: Manually drawn.

Answer (score 1):

User drawn objects are not accesible via pinescript.

You need to draw your objects programmatically and then you can check if the price is in the rectangle.

See [drawings](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Drawings.html) for more information.